# Laravel Raw and Eloquent Queries

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

I've got a table `transactions` which has a `paymentable_id` and `paymentable_type` column, for polymorphic relations. I have a `Plan` model, used for payment plans. Whenever a transaction for that plan is made, the transactions will be related to that plan, using the polymorphic relation.

Now, I want to fetch all `Plans` from the database, including a field called `total_amount`. The `total_amount` field should include the sum of all `transactions.amount` related for that plan.

So far, and with help from another question I asked, I came up with the following:

```
$plans = App\Models\Plan::all('*', DB::RAW("(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE paymentable_id = plans.id AND paymentable_type = 'App\\\\Models\\\\Plan' ) as total_amount") );
```

Which works totally fine. However, I feel this is just plain wrong:

```
WHERE paymentable_id = plans.id AND paymentable_type = 'App\\\\Models\\\\Plan'
```

Also, the need to specify the `paymentable_id` AND `paymentable_type` seems wrong to me. I need to be doing this for a lot of other queries as well, since the polymorphic relation can contain up to 5 different models.

Question 1. Is the above a correct query to use and if so, is there perhaps also a "better way" to create that query?

Question 2. The below query also works but I perhaps do not understand this part:

```
->join('transactions', 'plans.id', '=', 'transactions.paymentable_id')
```

Whenever I include the `->where('transactions.paymentable_id', '=', 'plans.id')`, it works as expected. But without that part, it basically ignores the `paymentable_id`.

```
$plans = DB::table('plans')->join('transactions', 'plans.id', '=', 'transactions.paymentable_id')
                           ->where('transactions.paymentable_type', '=', 'App\\Models\\Plan')
                           ->get([DB::raw('sum(transactions.amount) as total_amount')]);
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do not know you data base

```
$plans = DB::table('plans')->join('transactions', 'plans.id', '=', 'transactions.paymentable_id')
                       ->where('transactions.paymentable_type', '=', 'you_plan_type')
                       ->select('plans.*','transactions.*')
                       ->selectRaw('sum(transactions.amount) as total_amount')
                       ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work, helped me learn some new stuff there, cool :